# SOCKET in winsock2.h not accepted in visual studio 2017

Tags: c++, macros, visual-studio-2017, winsock2

Getting error i freetds headers when i include them in my VS 2017 c++ project

in tds.h when i include that in my project

```
    include\tds.h(1331): error C3646: 's': unknown override specifier
    include\tds.h(1331): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
    include\tds.h(1641): error C2065: 'TDS_SYS_SOCKET': undeclared identifier
    include\tds.h(1641): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 's'
```

I am trying to use freetds 0.91.100 version in my c++ application which was built using VS 2010. It was fine then.

Now after migrating my C++ project to VS 2017 i am getting strange errors.
I have built freetds lib as well in VS 2017.

freetds has this declaration in tds_sysdep_private.h

```
#if !defined(__WIN32__) && !defined(_WIN32) && !defined(WIN32)
typedef int TDS_SYS_SOCKET;
#define INVALID_SOCKET -1
#define TDS_IS_SOCKET_INVALID(s) ((s) < 0)
#else
typedef SOCKET TDS_SYS_SOCKET;
#define TDS_IS_SOCKET_INVALID(s) ((s) == INVALID_SOCKET)
#endif
```

and the tds.h has

```
struct tds_socket
{
TDS_SYS_SOCKET s;       /**< tcp socket, INVALID_SOCKET if not connected */
}
```

And the error is on this TDS_SYS_SOCKET declaration

My code include this header this way.

tdsloader.h

```
using namespace std;
#if defined (__cplusplus)
extern "C" {
#endif
#include "tds.h"
#if defined (__cplusplus)
}
#endif
```

As per the declaration of TDS_SYS_SOCKET in tds_sysdep_private.h , in case of windows build it is defined as SOCKET which is from winsock2.h

I read in other threads that the order of header file includion is important and i made sure that winsock2.h is included before windows.h or any other windows header file.

Now that SOCKET from winsock2.h is
     typedef UINT_PTR        SOCKET;

which in an unsigned , why is VS 2017 not able to recognize the type ?

Build should go through smoothly as it did in VS 2010.

Now with VS 2017 it shows build errors.

Comment: can some one tell me the reason for negative rating as well ?

Comment: Probably because you didn't provide an MCVE.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @DeepakSelvakumar Did you include tds_sysdep_private.h before including tds.h?

Comment: @MarcinZawiejski tds.h internally includes  tds_sysdep_private.h before anything else. All these were getting built properly in VS 2010. I dont understand what is the difference now.

Comment: @DeepakSelvakumar Unfortunately can't help you without a MCVE because it works fine for me as per the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the include order that works fine with VS 2017:

```
#include <tds_sysdep_private.h>
#include <tds.h>
```

alternatively you can:

```
#define _FREETDS_LIBRARY_SOURCE
#include <tds.h>
```

Comment: this order should be followed in the cpp where we use tds ? you have not modified anything inside the freetds lib header files ? what version of freetds are you using ?

Comment: It's for freetds version 0.91.100, no changes to the header files. In fact you don't need to include WinSock2.h and Windows.h because tds_sysdep_private.h already includes them.

Comment: i am using the same version 0.91.100. Yes, tds_sysdep_private.h includes winsoc2.h and windows.h. and tds.h includes tds_sysdep_private.h. Hence, it is okay to only include tds.h, Correct ? as you have mentioned in the second option.

Comment: Yes, it seems correct to include only tds.h but you have to #define _FREETDS_LIBRARY_SOURCE as this causes tds.h to include tds_sysdep_private.h.